# WooCommerce Product Search box with 3 dropdown menus

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have the following WooCommerce business case. There is a webshop for car parts and the visitor has the ability to search by: Car brand (automerk), car model (automodel) and car building year (autobouwjaar).

Here is an example of a working solution: https://fullcartuning.nl/ Search by car (Zoek op auto)

I try to figure out how I can achieve the search functionality. In the first place I was thinking to use categories with subcategories, but I think there is a more elegant way?

Below I have an example import file.

[image: 1]

We are using product variations.

Comment: Perhaps consider a JS/JQuery based approach? i.e. output a table/list in HTML then use JS to search/filter more intuitively and quickly? Possibly not the exact solution you need but see isotope.js as an example of filtering content this way. You would still want the Cat/SubCat hierarchy IMHO but this might make the user experience better?

Comment: @t2pe sounds like a good solutions for the interface, but I'm struggling how to store this data ;).

Comment: I already resolved this by creating 3 widgets and hide the dropdown menu's with a piece of JS code.